# How to add a coloured legend box to a pie chart with Chart.js v1?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, legend

I am trying to add a legend box to a pie chart with Chart.js v1.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="TheLegendOfDeviceChart"></div>
<canvas id="deviceChart" style="height:250px"></canvas>
```

And this is my Javascript code:

```
var pieChartCanvas = $("#deviceChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
var PieData = [
                {
                    value: 700,
                    color: "#f56954",
                    highlight: "#f56954",
                    label: "Chrome"
                },
                {
                    value: 500,
                    color: "#00a65a",
                    highlight: "#00a65a",
                    label: "IE"
                },
                // other values
            ];
var pieOptions = {
     // some options
     legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
     };

var pie = pieChart.Pie(PieData, pieOptions);
document.getElementById('TheLegendOfDeviceChart').innerHTML = pie.generateLegend();
```

This is what I get:

[A pie chart with a monochromatic legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w7wF.png)

But I would like to have a coloured legend box like this:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-introduction

How can I modify my legendTemplate to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use Chart.js 2.0 to get the legend that you desire.  What is the reason you are wanting to use 1.0?  It is no longer supported and the last release was Apr 5, 2016.

I highly recommend switching to 2.0 and then you can easily take advantage of the new legends.

If for whatever reason you cannot use 2.0 and must stick to 1.0, then you need to correct your `legendTemplate` property.  Based on the fiddle you provided yours is:

```
legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
```

It's hard to tell since its a long string, but this HTML template results in an empty `<span>` which should otherwise contain your dataset label.  Remember, an empty span will not render anything even if it has a `background` color defined.  Here is the resulting legend HTML once its rendered to demonstrate what I mean.

[image]

Per the [Chart.js v1 docs](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v1.1.0/docs/05-Pie-Doughnut-Chart.md), the correct `legendTemplate` string should be.

```
legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></span></li><%}%></ul>"
```

The difference being that the `<span>` contains the dataset label (and therefore displays correctly with colored background).  However, even this default looks pretty bad.

Fortunately, this is just standard HTML and CSS so you can style your legend however you see fit.  I would recommend you create a legend in HTML that you like, them convert it to a string and add in the necessary chart.js template expressions (e.g. `<% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%`, `<%=segments[i].fillColor%>`, etc).

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/bqwRaR) using a quick legend template that I came up with that looks pretty close to the Chart.js v2 template.  For completeness, I've also provided the key parts below.

css:

```
.indicator_box {
  width: 55px;
  height: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

Template String:

```
"<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li style=\"float: left; clear: both;\"><div class=\"indicator_box\" style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></div><span style=\"font-size: 20px;\"><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></span></li><%}%></ul>"
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vrwjfg9z/3649/

Comment: @EstevaoLuis Thanks for providing the fiddle.  I updated my answer to guide you in building a template that you desire.  Be sure to read through it and checkout my example codepen.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working now. I removed the `clear: both;` style in the li tag in order to have a horizontal legend list